# mobile access layout request

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

The site doesn’t show some menus, like the "review" and "meta". So to use it I typed in the url.

Also the suggested questions that appear when you are creating a question didn't show either.

And the tags are having the same problem, no auto complete and even after I write down they doesn't appear to accept the text as a tag.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should post it in SO meta. If you guys think it is appropriated you can migrate to there

Comment: And no chat T_T

Comment: "Meta" is in the footer navigation on mobile. I think it's a bad spot for it because *who looks at footers*? Especially when it's in the top menu on desktop and the mobile has a top menu? But it exists.

Comment: Seems to me like the Mobile version of Stack is a sad excuse for a Stack App.  But it's no worse than the mobile version of most sites...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The site doesn’t show some menus, like the "review" and "meta". So to use it I typed in the url.

I don't believe we have any plans right now to provide a mobile view for /review. It's not as simple as it might seem at first - we'd have to carefully consider how to structure the instructions for the different queues as well as still meaningfully show the posts under review and the available actions. There's just too much information there that's, at best, hard to fit on a phone screen. (Probably not as bad on a tablet, but we can't rely on folks just visiting from tablets.)

The other links, however, are there - you can find the link to the site's meta and to chat at the bottom of the page when you're using the mobile view.

> Also the suggested questions that appear when you are creating a question didn't show either.

This is currently by design due to the lack of screen real estate. Personally, I think this is a good thing on Arqade since suggested questions are often related to other games anyway. :)

> And the tags are having the same problem, no auto complete and even after I write down they doesn't appear to accept the text as a tag.

I get auto-complete in Safari on iOS 6.1.3. If it's not working for you, it may be a bug.

Comment: I'm sorry. I really didn't look at the footer. And I know that is FAR from easy to Create a good layout for the reviewers but I got curious about. Thanks for the replay

Answer (score 2):

On high-resolution phone screens or on tablets, the best way to get the full set of Stack tools is to turn on the Desktop version. You can find a link to do this in the footer, labelled `full site`. It will turn off the mobile interface entirely. To return to the mobile view, find the link labelled `mobile` in the footer of the desktop interface.

I find on an iPhone with a "Retina" display it works well enough for some things, like checking out the reivew queue, but I stick with the mobile interface most of the time. On a good tablet you might never need to go back to the mobile interface.